# NGRX - combine selectors with props

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

How do I combine reducers, when one of them needs props?

I have following model:

```
interface Device {
  id: string;
  data: IDeviceData;
}
```

and DeviceReducer that looks as follow:

```
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { Device } from '../model/device';
import { SubnetBrowserApiActions } from 'src/app/explorer/actions';

export interface State extends EntityState<Device> { }

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Device> = createEntityAdapter<Device>();

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState();

export function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action:
    | SubnetBrowserApiActions.SubnetBrowserApiActionsUnion
): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SubnetBrowserApiActions.SubnetBrowserApiActionTypes.LoadEntriesSucces: {
      return adapter.upsertMany(action.payload.entries, state);
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

const {
  selectAll,
} = adapter.getSelectors();

export const getAllDevices = selectAll;
```

In my other reducer, when I want to select devices using an array of ids I use this code:

```
export const getVisibleDrives = createSelector(
  [fromRoot.getAllDevices, getVisibleDrivesSerialNumbers],
  (devices, visibleDevicesIds) =>
    devices.filter((device) => onlineDevicesIds.includes(device.serialNumber)),
);
```

This code is very repetitive, so I'd like to add add parametrized selector that will return just these drives, that have id in array that I pass as prop. What I tried to do looks as follows:

**Additional selector in DeviceReduced**

```
export const getDrivesWithIds = (ids: string[]) => createSelector(
  getAllDevices,
  devices => devices.filter(device => ids.includes(device.id))
);
```

And then combine them in the **following** way:

```
export const getVisibleDrives = createSelector(
  getVisibleDrivesSerialNumbers,
  (ids) => fromRoot.getDrivesWithIds
);
```

Issue here is that the returned type of this selector is

`(ids: string[]) => MemoizedSelector<State, Device[]>`

Which makes it impossible for me to do anything useful with this selector. As an example I'd like to filter this list by keyword, and I am not able to use `filter` method on it:

**Example usage**

```
export const getFilteredVisibleDrives = createSelector(
  [getVisibleDrives, getKeywordFilterValue],
  (visibleDrives, keywordFilter) => {
    return visibleDrives
      .filter(drive => // in this line there is an error: Property 'filter' does not exist on type '(ids: string[]) => MemoizedSelector<State, Device[]>'
        drive.ipAddress.toLowerCase().includes(keywordFilter.toLowerCase()) ||
        drive.type.toLowerCase().includes(keywordFilter.toLowerCase()) ||
        drive.userText.toLowerCase().includes(keywordFilter.toLowerCase())
      );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See my post [NgRx: Parameterized selectors](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors)
for more info.

### Update: NgRx v13+

Selector with props are deprecated, use selector factories instead:

Selector:

```
export const getCount = (props: {id: number, multiply:number}) =>   
  createSelector(     
    (state) => state.counter[props.id],     
    (counter) => counter * props.multiply
  );
```

Component:

```
this.counter2 = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromRoot.getCount({ id: 'counter2', multiply: 2 })
);   
this.counter4 = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromRoot.getCount({ id: 'counter4', multiply: 4 })
);
```

### Deprecated

Selector:

```
export const getCount = () =>   
  createSelector(     
    (state, props) => state.counter[props.id],     
    (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply
  );
```

Component:

```
this.counter2 = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter2', multiply: 2 })
);   
this.counter4 = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromRoot.getCount(), { id: 'counter4', multiply: 4 })
);
```

Comment: how does this work in a case where you might define reducers at the "Feature" level and then make them global outside the feature? I tried, but it isn't working: https://gist.github.com/mindscratch/22d507f8401dc9f78627db8c61b3f931

Comment: @timdeschryver - can you please update your answer to include syntax for v13 where selectors props are deprectaed!

Comment: Thanks @AakashGoplani - it's updated.